# CSS targetting last child container of class

Tags: html, css

Not sure this is possible with CSS only. Any help is appreciated.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="row invoice with-tax">
    <div class="mobile-body-header mobile"><strong>Items</strong></div>
    <div class="invoice-item">
        <div class="item-filler"></div>
        <div class="quantity">2</div>
        <div class="amount-mobile total">$13,336.60</div>
        <div class="item-number">ABC123</div>
        <div class="title"><span class="quantity-mobile">2 x </span>Dance classes and tutoring for upcoming Michael Jacksons</div>
        <div class="amount-item-ex">$153.00</div>
        <div class="amount-subtotal">$306.00</div>
        <div class="amount-tax">$30.60</div>
        <div class="amount-total total">$13,336.60</div>
        <div class="item-filler"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="invoice-item">
        <div class="item-filler"></div>
        <div class="quantity">2</div>
        <div class="amount-mobile total">$13,336.60</div>
        <div class="item-number">ABC123</div>
        <div class="title"><span class="quantity-mobile">2 x </span>Dance classes and tutoring for upcoming Michael Jacksons</div>
        <div class="amount-item-ex">$153.00</div>
        <div class="amount-subtotal">$306.00</div>
        <div class="amount-tax">$30.60</div>
        <div class="amount-total total">$13,336.60</div>
        <div class="item-filler"></div>
    </div>
    ....
 </div>
```

I am trying to remove the `border-bottom` of the final `div` with class `title` in the last `div` with class `invoice-item`. These are essentially rows of `div` elements that can vary in numbers (as it is and invoice I am working on).

I have tried unsuccessfully the examples below. Although I can see it working in the Fiddle from @Steve below it is not removing the last border when placed inside the rest of the `CSS`. And I can confirm the border is set just above per the examples below.

```
div.invoice-item > div.title {
    border-bottom: 2px dotted red;
}
div.invoice-item:last-child > div.title {
    border: none !important; 
}
```

also

```
div.invoice-item > div.title {
    border-bottom: 2px dotted red;
}
div.invoice > div.invoice-item:last-child > div.title {
    border: none !important; 
}
```

also

```
div {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
div.invoice-item:last-of-type > div.title {
  border: none;
}
```

Comment: What are you seeing?

Comment: Your first answer seems to work fine, per https://jsfiddle.net/3gf06364/  - it's possible you have a border set by a stronger selector elsewhere?

Comment: Can you post the CSS that's defining the border?

Comment: Try `border: none!important;` to override stronger selectors?

Comment: Hi @Steve, thanks! I should have tried the JSFiddle route to isolate. I will work with your suggestion. Many thanks!

Comment: @TheRealPapa see my answer, it should work as long as it is after any other styling (unless the prior styles have `!important`)

Comment: I see it works in the fiddle, but not in my CSS. I have traced and there is only once the border is set, just above the statement I am trying to fix. I will add this to my question above so you can see. `!important;` has not fixed it.

Comment: Can you try something like `background-color: red` or `font-size: 30px` to see if your problem is about the css `selector` or about `border` property?

Comment: @TheRealPapa see update

Comment: Hi @Naourass I tried `font-size: 30px;` and `font-size: 10px;` but it all remains at `30px`.

Comment: @TheRealPapa Then the problem is about the selector, you are missing something in the syntax... Maybe a `>`, a `/` or something else. Or your structure HTML is different from which is shown above. Another thing, are the original CSS styles witten in a CSS file, directly in HTML or via Javascript/jQuery?

Comment: @Nauurass it is an email template so the styles are at the top of the file. Hmmm. Detective work continues. Thanks!

Comment: @TheRealPapa is there any `defered` or asynchronous JS (`<script async>`)?

Comment: @TheRealPapa Not all e-mail clients support `:last-child`. Check my answer's update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's an e-mail template, there are some [clients](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) that doesn't support `:last-child`. Instead of using `:last-child`, try to add a new Class to the `div` that you want to select.

Comment: Hi @Naourass thanks for this suggestion. I will have to code the last row class when I build the template dynamically.

Comment: Just add a new class to those `div`s. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try    `div.invoice-item:last-of-type > div.title { border: none; }`

**UPDATE**

Since there's an unknown CSS evil, here's a trick that might work:

`div.invoice-item:last-of-type > div.title.title { border: none !important; }`

---

```css
div {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
/* div.invoice-item:last-of-type > div.title {
  border: none;
} */

div.invoice-item:last-of-type > div.title.title {
  border: none !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="row invoice with-tax">
  <div class="mobile-body-header mobile"><strong>Items</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="invoice-item">
    <div class="item-filler"></div>
    <div class="quantity">2</div>
    <div class="amount-mobile total">$13,336.60</div>
    <div class="item-number">ABC123</div>
    <div class="title"><span class="quantity-mobile">2 x </span>Dance classes and tutoring for upcoming Michael Jacksons</div>
    <div class="amount-item-ex">$153.00</div>
    <div class="amount-subtotal">$306.00</div>
    <div class="amount-tax">$30.60</div>
    <div class="amount-total total">$13,336.60</div>
    <div class="item-filler"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="invoice-item">
    <div class="item-filler"></div>
    <div class="quantity">2</div>
    <div class="amount-mobile total">$13,336.60</div>
    <div class="item-number">ABC123</div>
    <div class="title"><span class="quantity-mobile">2 x </span>Dance classes and tutoring for upcoming Michael Jacksons</div>
    <div class="amount-item-ex">$153.00</div>
    <div class="amount-subtotal">$306.00</div>
    <div class="amount-tax">$30.60</div>
    <div class="amount-total total">$13,336.60</div>
    <div class="item-filler"></div>
  </div>
  ....
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @zer00ne, thansk for the help, but per above suggestion although I can see it work on the fiddle it does not for me and I cannot seem to see why. The border is being set just above the statement I am trying to fix.

Comment: @TheRealPapa You tried the update? `div.invoice-item:last-of-type > div.title.title { border: none !important; }`

Comment: Hi @ze00ne yes I did but result is the same. Something else is causing this not to work. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @TheRealPapa You doubled the `.title`? (e.g. `div.title.title`)

Comment: @TheRealPapa I think we need a fiddle with all CSS included.